# Copy & paste in non-canonical mod

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I'm creating a program to implement a linux shell

I've changed terminal mod into non-canonical

```
void    ft_getch_prepare(void)
{
int             ret;
struct termios  new_opts;

ret = tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &new_opts);
new_opts.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK
        | ECHONL | ECHOPRT | ECHOKE | ICRNL);
new_opts.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
new_opts.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
ret += tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_opts);
}

int     ft_getch(void)
{
int c;

c = 0;
ft_getch_prepare();
read(0, &c, 4);
return (c);
}
```

but when I want to copy a string and paste it, it only show the first character of the copied string

For example, I want to paste this string `"HELLO WORLD"` into my terminal, but 
it only shows the first character `"H"`

Comment: Could you provide a full example?  I tried to complete you snipset and it is behaving as I expect.

Comment: i did it's my ft_getch() that read user input , When i remove ECHO the paste is working correctly but when i enable it , it only paste one char

Comment: Note: although it seems unlikely to be part of the problem, it will be very inefficient to call `ft_getch_prepare()` on every call to `ft_getch()`.  I recommend calling it (no more than) *once*, before reading anything.

Comment: Note, too, that you probably want to discriminate between the case of input from a terminal and input from a non-terminal (e.g. redirected from a file or pipe,  or read from a command-line argument).  It is not safe to assume that the standard input is a terminal, but you can check with `isatty()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ICRNL` flag constant applies to `c_iflag`, not `c_lflag`.  You are turning it off in the wrong place.  It is unclear to me why you're turning it off *at all*, but if you want to do so, then you need to modify the correct flag set.

The `ECHOE`, `ECHOL`, `ECHONL`, `ECHOPRT`, and `ECHOKE` local-mode flags are only relevant in canonical mode, which you are turning off.  It should not be harmful to turn these off, too, but it does make your code harder to read and follow than it needs to be.

With respect to

> when I want to copy a string and paste it, it only show the first character of the copied string

, I suspect you're being bitten by the input timer and / or minimum character count properties of non-canonical mode.  These are controlled by the `c_cc[VTIME]` and `c_cc[VMIN]` elements of the "special characters" array in your termios structure.  If you are configuring a terminal that will support interactive input, or for which there may otherwise be unbounded-length pauses in input, then you need to turn off the timer and ensure that reads block properly by setting

```
new_opts.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
new_opts.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
```

. I am uncertain whether that will be sufficient for your purposes, however, in part because I cannot judge whether the manner in which you are reading the input contributes to the issue.

**UPDATE**:

Since you've now disclosed your input function, I can say that you indeed do have significant problems there if it is supposed to provide an interface equivalent to `getc()`.  You are reading four bytes at a time instead of one, and you are not handling EOF or errors properly.  Moreover, the multi-byte read introduces the possibility of *short* reads, which you do not detect or handle.

If you're trying to read a single character at a time, then *do that*.  The return value of `getc()` is `int` instead of `char` not because it's appropriate to try to read `int`s from the stream but to provide for result values that are not valid `char`s -- specifically, `EOF`.

I decline to rewrite your code for you, but to emulate `getc()`, it needs to do this:

- read a single `char` at a time
- check the return value of `read`.  If it is anything other than 1 (for a one-character read) then return `EOF`
- otherwise, return the char read, *converted to type `unsigned char`*.

Comment: i must work with 4 bytes , cuz i'm using termcaps and key detections to move the cursor (up , down, left ...)

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant at this level, @haxor12.  You cannot rely on your input to come in multiples of four bytes, and if some of it arrives in four-byte units then you cannot rely on those to occur at offsets from the start of input that are multiples of four bytes.  Instead, you need to recognize those in the *byte* stream.  That's how the terminal delivers data to you: a byte stream, not an integer stream.  You need to recognize that and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If I complete your program with

```
int main()
{
    int i = ft_getch();
    printf("%x\n", i);
}
```

I get

```
$ ./a.out
4c4c4548
```

when I try to paste HELLO WORLD which is what I expect. (48 is the hexadecimal code for H, 45 for E, 4C for L; it look reversed as I'm on a little endian architecture).